# Norton Internet Security 2011 Beta Affecting Localhost Performance?

Tags: php, localhost, wamp, norton-internet-security

I don't know why, but after I installed Norton Internet Security 2011 beta, the PHP scripts that I'm working on in WampServer became painfully slow. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not running the beta (didn't even know there was one), but you may want to let Symantec know about this - if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try excluding the directory the scripts reside in from Norton's scan.  Also try disabling On-Access Internet Scanning (or whatever it's called in Norton).

Comment: I figured it out, I tried disabling the smart firewall which is a feature of nis 2011.